# Can I take a photograph and change it's background in mdframed, includegraphics setting?

Tags: graphics, color, mdframed

Is there a way to change the background colour of a photograph within the `\begin{mdframed}`, `\begin{figure}` and `\includegraphics{filename}`. My `mdframed` environment is coloured, but my photograph has a white background. Does anyone know how I can change this?

Comment: `mdframed` is not photoshop!. Remove the white background from photo using say, imagemagick or gimp or photo shop and then the background colour of `mdframed` box will be the background.

Comment: You can use masks with the PGF image inclusion facilities. But you would still need to create the mask in a suitable application. It would surely be easier to do as @HarishKumar recommends.